# How to correctly use "as much/as many" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Which of these following sentences are correct?

1. John received twice as many votes as Harry.
2. John received twice as many vote as Harry did.
3. John received twice as many vote as Harry.
4. John received twice as many votes as Harry's.
5. Apples cost twice as much as oranges do.
6. Apples cost twice as much as oranges.

Comment: (3) and (4) are ungrammatical, as you know. All the rest are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most contexts, the simple versions are correct and perfectly acceptable. There are variations in syntax you can use, such as possessives, and switching nouns for verbs. Here are some examples of using "as much as" and "twice":

I weigh twice as much as John.

My weight is twice that of John's.

I'm twice as heavy as John.

It's not wrong, but it's unnecessary, to add the omitted verbs:

I weigh twice as much as John does.
My weight is twice that of John's weight.
I'm twice as heavy as John is.